# How to overcome "do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make changes to your device"?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I am using Visual Studio Installer 2017 to create a setup file and its running perfectly. However, I have a question regarding the setup file. Whenever I start installation file, it pops up and says

> Do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make
>   changes to your device?

If I say Yes, the application gets installed.

Is it possible to remove this message whenever I install my application in Visual Studio Installer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Visual Studio Installer, but generally you need to sign the code with an Authenticode certificate.  Obtaining one is process, not an event, and I believe will cost both time and money.  See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537361(v=vs.85)

Even then, it may take time to become a trusted publisher in Microsoft's eyes.